# Modules' names contain unicode characters. How to have them not encoded in suggestion?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, unicode, filenames, urlencode

Is there a way to tell VS Code to not apply [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) for module names? All the files are saved in UTF-8 so I guess there should be no worry of using Unicode characters in file names and variables. If I manually type the Unicode URLs then it still work. At the very least I want it to automatically decode the URLs when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I hope this is a joke. Most Vietnamese standard keyboards wouldn't let you type these variables. Also what's wrong with encoding those URLs?

Comment: @LukeVo nope. It's real effort. I just add a space manually after each word then delete the spaces. The problem of encoding those URLs is that it's ugly and hard for me to know which file is which

Comment: URLs don't support unicode. You can't do that

Comment: @Konrad but if so, then why does it still work if I manually type the unicode URLs? At the very least I want it to automatically decode the URLs when I press Enter

Comment: It's not applying URL encoding. It's decoding your malformed URLs (derived from file names, but still URLs). URLs can only consist of certain ASCII characters. Anything you've seen to the contrary (especially in browsers) are attempts to make them appear friendly for non-technical users in order to gain greater market share. That said, there's probably an extension for doing what you ask. However, asking about what extensions are available is outside the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: @Ouroborus but this is OSes and IDEs, not browsers. Or do you mean that under the hood, OSes and IDEs only store ASCII paths too? And when I type Unicode into paths, they immediately encode my characters? What do you mean by malformed URLs? How is that different to encoding non-ASCII characters?

Comment: "Browser" was an example. Yes, under the hood. (Where exactly depends.) Once upon a time, you could **only** use ascii, even in typing or viewing urls. Then unicode was invented and, as time went on, various user/machine translation layers were built. It takes effort to make such a translation layer. VS Code doesn't have such a translation layer and probably won't. What it does have is a powerful extension interface. So, as I said, there's probably an extension for that. If there isn't, you may be able to write one.